# setq of case-sensitivity in .emacs has no effect

Tags: variables, emacs, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, dot-emacs

I have a lot of custom stuff in my .emacs file: fonts, colors, window sizing, key bindings, etc.  All of it works.

Then at the end, I just added a: `(setq case-fold-search nil)`. It's a variable that when set to `nil` is supposed to make search case-sensitive in all emacs modes. It doesn't for me.

Setting `case-fold-search` to `nil` in an individual buffer works, but when I set it in `.emacs`, it doesn't work. Is there a reason why a setq declaration in a `.emacs` may not work sometimes? How should I try to debug the issue?

Comment: `(setq-default 'case-fold-search nil)`

Comment: i found that i have to remove the `'` or else that statement won't work (in .emacs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal behavior for buffer-local variables.  `setq-default` can be used to establish a default value for them.

You can determine that a variable is buffer local by checking out its documentation, using <kbd>C-h v case-fold-search</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x describe-variable</kbd>), which in this case reports (*note 4th line)*:

```
case-fold-search is a variable defined in `buffer.c'.
Its value is t

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.

Documentation:
*Non-nil if searches and matches should ignore case.

You can customize this variable.
```

Comment: Also note that `C-h v case-fold-search RET` tells you if the variable is buffer-local.