# Emacs Case Sensitive Replace String

Tags: emacs, replace, case-sensitive, dot-emacs

I just asked a related question ([setq question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5345051/627517)) but it's distinctly different, so I decided to branch off with this question.

In my `.emacs` file, I define a key binding to the `replace-string` command:

```
(define-key global-map "\C-r" 'replace-string)
```

`replace-string` does basic search and replace. Assuming the first letter of the search string is lowercase, if the `case-fold-search` is `nil` then `replace-string` does case-sensitive search, otherwise it does case-insensitive search.

The problem is that `case-fold-search` controls the "case-sensitiveness" of both "search" (like the `search-forward` command) and "search and replace" (like the `replace-string` command).

The question is how do I make **JUST** the `replace-string` command (or anything `C-r` is bound to) case-sensitive, leaving the `search-forward` case-insensitive as it is by default.

Perhaps I would need to set `case-fold-search` to `nil` just for the `replace-string` command, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this in your .emacs:

```
(defadvice replace-string (around turn-off-case-fold-search)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'replace-string)
```

This does exactly what you said, set `case-fold-search` to `nil` just for `replace-string`.

In fact this is almost exactly the example in the [Emacs Lisp reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-Old-Advice.html).

*Edit on 2021-11-02:* as the link above indicates, `defadvice` is no longer the recommended way to implement this. The new recommended implementation would be

```
(defun with-case-fold-search (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((case-fold-search t))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'replace-string :around #'with-case-fold-search)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this method, which does not require advice:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-r") 
    (lambda () 
      (interactive) 
      (let ((case-fold-search nil)) 
        (call-interactively 'replace-string))))
```